# WSO2 APIM - Disabling SSL/Https

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to disable SSL\HTTPS in WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 but it always redirects to https endpoint during authentication. How to make it work only on http so that i can configure SSL off loading in load balancer ?

Comment: Hi Pradeep, are you trying to access carbon console, publisher, and devportal apps via http?

Comment: Yes Tharika, our requirement is to perform SSL offload at load balancer level and further call to WSO2 should be over http.